# time data in byte not matching format

Tags: python, strptime

```
last_appended_row_timestamp = datetime.strptime(str(last_appended_row_timestamp), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The code here yields an error saying,

> ValueError: time data "b'2019-12-08 23:59:59'" does not match format
>   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'.

`b'2019-12-08 23:59:59'` is byte, and putting the byte in `str()`, I got the result. What is the problem?? Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

```py
str(b'2')
>>> "b'2'"
```

So you need change your code, like this:

```py
datetime.strptime(last_appended_row_timestamp.decode('u8'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```